# Can I launch X11.app for 32-bit Mac OS X on 64-bit one?

Tags: macos, 64-bit, 32-bit, xorg, x-server

I need to run 32-bit X11.app on 64-bit Mac OS X. Is it possible? If yes, which version, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, though I can't help out more until you tell us what OS version you have and maybe what X11.app version. Personally, for Snow Leopard I use [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/trac/wiki) instead of the X11 that Apple ships (shipped?) with the OS.